# Renaming files by date solaris

Tags: rsync, opensolaris

I’m trying to run the following command

```
rsync -avz /mnt/backups/`date \
    --date=yesterday +\%Y-\%m-\%d`-`date \
    --date=yesterday +\%A`/server1/ /mnt/backups/`date \
        +\%Y-\%m-\%d`-`date +\%A`/server1/
```

The problem is I don't know how to change this from Ubuntu syntax to solaris which I have been asked to write a rsync script for. It doesn't like the `date --date=yesterday +\%Y-\%m-\%d`-`date --date=yesterday +\%A`part. How would I write this part of the code so solaris understand it, I have had a read of the man page but couldn't get it to work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solaris has some old and crispy userland. It has no options for changing date while formatting.

http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E23824_01/html/821-1461/date-1.html#scrolltoc

However you can switch to GNU tools: http://www.sunsolarisadmin.com/solaris-11/gnu-tools-out-of-the-box-in-solaris-11/

Comment: Can you name your solaris then? Solaris 8 has no such possibilities at all: http://johnmeister.com/CS/UNIX/SOLARIS/MAN/date-man.html

Comment: Solaris 11, i know but i thought solaris 11 might do

Comment: You have no luck with this one.

Comment: the tools come with solaris 11, don't think im going to have much luck with this one

Comment: I've mean stock date.